# Display a google image picture in a GUI window

Tags: image, swing, jlabel

I am coding in Java on Eclipse IDE, and I cannot figure out how to display an image using a link. I have not been able to determine how to do output an image. I need to know the proper import statements as well as how to structure a simple GUI to contain it. I have almost no experience with GUI. I have worked with JLabel. What would be the best way to display an image using a link in Java?

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot figure out how to display an image using a link.

You can use a `URL` to specify the resource name and then `ImageIO` to read the file:

```
URL url = new URL("http://somewhere.com/someFile.jpg");
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(url);
JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon( bi ) );
```

> I need to know the proper import statements as well as how to structure a simple GUI to contain it. I have almost no experience with GUI. I have worked with JLabel.

Start by reading the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. Maybe the section on "How to Use Icons" or "How to Use Labels". The demo code there will help you get started.